# how to get the response from an ajax request with application/x-octet-stream?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, resources, jsonp

i am using jsonp to get some content from a api.

the issue is that the link i have returns a file to be saved as CSV and the response is `application/x-octet-stream`.

if i look in chrome developer tools i get this error `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/x-octet-stream:...` and `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`.

but, if i look in the `preview` or `response` tabs i can see my data.

is there a way to grab that data?

one solution would be for me to setup different headers in php, but my entire page will break

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: @ShuklaSannidhya how would i use that with $.ajax({.... and jsonp?

Comment: `dataType: "text"` should work in your `$.ajax` options

Comment: @Orangepill note. dataType must be jsonp

Comment: but you are saying it is responding with CSV.

Comment: sure. but anything else than jsonp will give an error. @ShuklaSannidhya had a good point with `xhr.responseType`, i'm looking into that now, though i get all kind of errors

Comment: I tried it with plain JavaScript (without any library). Just a simple XHR to a CSV without changing the `requestHeader` or `responseType` will work. I don't know how to do that in jQuery though.

Comment: @ShuklaSannidhya can u share some code. In my case i get an error that `xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer"` is not supported

Comment: Sorry my bad... `"arraybuffer"` is for binary files not for `"application/x-whatever"`. Just use a simple XHR, it'll work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
function main() {
    var xhr;

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "foo.csv?r=" + Math.random(), true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            //xhr.responseText stores your CSV Content
            document.querySelector("body").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

Comment: 302 is not error => 302 Found is a common way of performing URL redirection.